# get latitude and longitude for locations in a file

Tags: android, geolocation, maps

I have a list of place around 900-1200

I would like to get each of their latitude and longitude in a File
like csv or anyother suitable format as i need to push it into a database.

would there be any possible code to do that..any method that would make it simple, as it would  be a very tedious task to find info of each place one by one

Comment: I didn't ask to do it..just to provide some useful link or resources that can get me started...its not my fault that i am a beginner in such stuffs and that doesn't mean i don't have the right to learn.(Have done a lot of googling and searches before posting here) Plus this question might help someone in future..

Comment: It is not a way to ask questions here.When asking questions you should always present to us what you've tried.Its totally Ok to be beginner.We all are.But the text like you've asked,simply shows a lackadaisical attitude.

Comment: I am sorry if you felt like So.. i have tried my best..and still doing it.cause this thing is important for me.

Comment: even i ask questions.Just read and try to find the difference:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15492160/yahoo-authorization-oauthoauth-problem-timestamp-refused

Comment: sure..will keep that in mind in future..anyways thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Google Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/)

It is of the format 
A Geocoding API request must be of the following form:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/output?parameters
```

where output may be either of the following values:

json (recommended) indicates output in JavaScript Object Notation (JSON)
xml indicates output as XML

```
Eg... 
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&sensor=true_or_false
```

For your problem, You can create a Javascript array of places and call this Google Geocoder in a loop and then [parse JSON](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/webservices/index#ParsingJSON) and populate another array with names of places and then push them to DB.

In case you want to parse it in Java use [Jackson JSON](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) or [Google GSON](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) , both works fine and are popular.

Comment: can you provide me a function or a link where i can see Google Geocoding Api in use.really confused how to do that..

Comment: @RahulMehrotra the very first link, in my answer (Google Geocoding API) https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/ in this link you will find the eg. query and the JSON response, parse it is very easy in Javascript

Comment: Have never used javascript before..thats the problem

Comment: @RahulMehrotra I have updated the answer with parsing it with Java, for other languages visit.. http://www.json.org/

Comment: @ AurA thanks a lot for your help..with some small tutorials of javascript i was able to get my work done..thanks