# Yahoo Authorization OAUTH:oauth_problem="timestamp_refused"

Tags: android, oauth, titanium-mobile, yahoo-api, yahoo-oauth

I have been following [Yahoo OAUTH guide](http://developer.yahoo.com/social/rest_api_guide/) closely and successfully established a connection and was able to retrieve the access token along with other objects which i get in response URI.But, now when i try to fetch the Contacts of the authenticated user i always get this Error no matter what NTP server i choose for my computers clock:

`Authentication error: Unable to respond to any of these challenges: {oauth=WWW-Authenticate: OAuth oauth_problem="timestamp_refused", realm="yahooapis.com"}`

Searching around i could know that i am not the only one experiencing this,but the 'solutions' included -

- Adding some time to the milliseconds which i pass as timestamp.([This](http://developer.yahoo.com/oauth/guide/oauth-make-request.html) is what i follow,i successfully gets me an access token but not when getting contacts)
- Synchronising the computer's clock to some good server.

Nevertheless, i tried these but getting the same error.

Here's a view of what i send:

```
var url = 'https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth/v2/get_token';
                url += '?oauth_nonce=' + 'somerandomstring';
                url += '&oauth_timestamp=' + timestamp;
                url += '&oauth_consumer_key=' + ConsumerKey;
                url += '&oauth_signature_method=' + 'plaintext';
                url += '&oauth_signature=' + ConsumerSecret + '%26' + oauth_token_secret;
                url += '&oauth_version=1.0';
                url += '&oauth_token=' + oauth_token;
                url += '&oauth_verifier=' + oauth_verifier;
```

Any valid help would be appreciated.

Comment: are you sending unix timestamp or other?which time stamp r u sending

Comment: nope i am sending a normal timestamp.. i am on windows 7 and am using simple `new Date().getTime()` to get the time

Comment: thats what the problem i guess u need to send Unix timestamp

Comment: but i am using the same code to get a `request token` and an `access token` which i am getting with the same sort of timestamp successfully

Comment: try using var unixtime = Date.parse("24-Nov-2009 17:57:35").getTime()/1000 like this...

Comment: why use that bad date? Yahoo would refuse it straight away because it would check with +-600 seconds time with their own server.Are you trying to tell me to divide what i get by 1000 and see?

Comment: I need milliseconds according to yahoo docs.

Comment: use this you will fet millisecoonds i mean change the date to now..keep your previous timestamp variable here  timestamp = Date.parse(timestamp).getTime()/1000

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11893083/convert-normal-date-to-unix-timestamp  check here

Comment: Plz wait m trying to do the changes.brb inshallah

Comment: it gives me an exception `TypeError:Object NaN has no method getTime`

Comment: by the ways will that code work on titanium code?

Comment: use this you will get surely ..i have tested       var currentdatetime = new Date();
       var timestamp=Date.parse(currentdatetime)/1000

Comment: i am getting `token rejected` now.I don't know if the problem is solved now.Anyways post your solution as an answer

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15928169/get-yahoo-contacts-in-android-using-oauth/15971268#15971268

Comment: uh, to clarify - you need seconds since 1970. Not milliseconds..